# Core Data Multithreading: Code Examples

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been having [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410131/hang-in-mergechangesfromcontextdidsavenotification-and-merge-conflicts) with my multi-threaded Core Data enabled app, and I figured I should take a hard look at what I'm doing and how.  Please let me know if the following should work.

I have a singleton `DataManager` class that handles the Core Data stuff.  It has a property `managedObjectContext` that returns a different MOC for each thread.  So, given `NSMutableDictionary *_threadContextDict` (string thread names to contexts) and `NSMutableDictionary *_threadDict` (string thread names to threads), it looks something like this:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
  if ([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread])
  {
    MyAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return delegate.managedObjectContext; //MOC created in delegate code on main thread
  }
  else
  {
    NSString *thisThread = [[NSThread currentThread] description];
    {
      if ([_threadContextDict objectForKey:thisThread] != nil)
      {
        return [_threadContextDict objectForKey:thisThread];
      }
      else
      {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]init];
        MyAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [_threadContextDict setObject:context forKey:thisThread];
        [_threadDict setObject:[NSThread currentThread] forKey:thisThread];

        //merge changes notifications
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
            name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];

        return context;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the `mergeChanges` method, I merge the changes from the incoming notification to all contexts except the one that generated the notification.  It looks like this:

```
-(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  MyAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;
  [context performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification)
     withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];

  for (NSString *element in [_threadContextDict allKeys])
  {
    if (![element isEqualToString:[[NSThread currentThread] description]])
    {
      NSThread *thread = [_threadDict objectForKey:element];
      NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [_threadContextDict objectForKey:element];
      [threadContext performSelector:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification)
         onThread:thread withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I save changes on a MOC, it's done with a call to a `saveContext` method on this shared `DataManager`, which calls `save` on a context obtained from the aforementioned property:

```
-(void)saveContext
{
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
  NSError *err = nil;
  [context save:&err];
  //report error if necessary, etc.
}
```

Given my understanding of the Core Data multithreading rules, I feel like this should work.  I'm using a separate context for each thread, but the same persistent store for all of them.  But when I use this, I get a lot of merge conflicts, even though my threads aren't working on the same objects (`NSManagedObject` subclasses).  I'm just downloading data from the network, parsing the results, and saving them to Core Data.

Am I doing something wrong?  I've tried using `NSLock` instances to lock around some things, but then I just get hangs.

**UPDATE/RESOLUTION**: I was able to make this work by adding one simple thing: a way to remove a thread/MOC pair from my dictionary when I'm finished with it.  At the end of each block in each call to `dispatch_async` where I do Core Data stuff, I call `[self removeThread]`, which removes the current thread and its MOC from the dictionary.  I also only merge changes to the main thread MOC.  Effectively, this means that every time I do work on a background thread, I get a fresh new MOC.

I also distinguish threads by adding a number to `userInfoDict`, instead of calling `description`.  The number is obtained by a readonly property on my class that returns a higher number each time it's called.

Comment: You accepted an answer, but were you able to resolve your issues? What did you do?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With all due respect, your approach is a nightmare, and it should be even worse to debug it to solve anything if there is a problem with it. First problem is this:

> I have a singleton DataManager

Do not have a singleton object that manages core data manipulation with different entities on different threads. Singletons are tricky to deal with, especially on multithreading environment, and is even a worse approach to use it with core data.

Second thing, do not use NSThread to work on multithreading. There are more modern APIs. Use Grand central dispatch or NSOperation/NSOperationQueue. Apple has encouraged people to move from NSThread since the introduction of blocks (iOS 4). And for future reference, do not use the description of an object the way you are using it. Descriptions are usually/mostly used for debugging purposes. The information there should not be used to compare. Not even the pointer value (which is why you should use isEqual instead of ==).

This is what you need to know about core data and multithreading:

1. Create one context per thread. The core data template has already created a main thread context for you. At the start of the execution of the background thread (inside the block, or on the main method of your NSOperation subclass), initialize your context.
2. Once your context is initialize, and has the right persistentStoreCoordinator, listen to the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. The object listening to the notification will receive the notification in the same thread the context was being saved. Since this is different than the main thread, do the merge call with the merging context on the thread the receiving context is being used. Let's say that you are using a context inside a thread different than the main thread, and you want to merge with the main thread, you need to call the merge method inside the main thread. You can do that with 
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//code here});
3. Do not use an NSManagedObject outside the thread where its managedObjectContext lives.

With these and other, simple rules, managing core data under a multithreading environment is easier. Your approach more difficult to implement, and worse to debug. Make some changes to your architecture. Manage the context depending on the thread you are working with (instead of centralized). Do not keep references to context outside of their scope. Once your first context is created, it is not expensive to be creating contexts on your threads. You can reuse the same context, as long as it's inside the same block/NSOperation execution.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty.  I don't see why my approach isn't obeying those rules, though.  My intent was to abstract away those rules so I didn't have to worry about them all through my code.  I'm using `NSThread` because I'm assuming I need to merge changes across all contexts (am I wrong here?), and that has to be done on each context's thread.  I haven't found a way with GCD to specify the thread a block should run on besides `dispatch_get_main_queue()` for the main thread.

Comment: Well, first, you should not be keeping references in order to access thread that aren't yours. Not even queues. If you want a queue, create your own using dispatch_queue_create("com.aname.aname", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL or DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT). To get a background queue, you can use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{//code here});. If you keep your context with short lives, keeping the syntonization is easier. Take a look at a relevant documentation information:

Comment: Changes you make to a managed object in one context are not propagated to a corresponding managed object in a different context unless you either refetch or re-fault the object. If you need to track in one thread changes made to managed objects in another thread, there are two approaches you can take, both involving notifications. For the purposes of explanation, consider two threads, “A” and “B”, and suppose you want to propagate changes from B to A.