# CoreData merge error saving context, with only one context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a setup in Core Data where I have a Profile object, which holds onto a to-many relationship of Pathology objects. Each of these has a to-many relationship to a number of Procedure objects. I'm attempting to add and remove items to each of these relationships. When a Pathology is added or removed, it's associated Procedures are also added or removed.

My problem is with Core Data saving. Currently I'm saving after every action. I can remove things just fine, and if this is the first time I've run the app, I can add them back in, too. If, however, I stop the app and start it up again, when I try to add a Pathology back, I get a Core Data error and a crash.

```
2013-07-18 14:33:41.879 MedEd[37063:907] ERROR saving managed object context! Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0xa2bd2c0 {conflictList=(
    "NSMergeConflict (0xa227cc0) for NSManagedObject (0x10875840) with objectID '0x1084f670 <x-coredata://4460E689-004A-456F-B65C-9CBAD20CCAE4/Resource/p1>' with oldVersion = 4 and newVersion = 5 and old cached row = {\n}",
    "NSMergeConflict (0xa289690) for NSManagedObject (0xa2cd850) with objectID '0xa2cd310 <x-coredata://4460E689-004A-456F-B65C-9CBAD20CCAE4/PeerVideo/p1>' with oldVersion = 4 and newVersion = <deleted> and old cached row = {}"
)}
```

(Contents of cached row removed)

I'm getting error 133020, which I've found out is a merge error. But I'm only using one context. Any help?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625232/failed-to-save-to-data-store-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-cocoa-error. One of the comments there says that changing `mergePolicy` on their managed object context to `NSOverwriteMergePolicy` resolved the issue for them.

Comment: Setting that now gives me the error `CoreData: error: (19) PRIMARY KEY must be unique`

Comment: I should mention that I'm not trying to add new objects to Core Data when I do this. I'm just attempting to add something into a relationship.

Comment: I have a very similar error, were you ever able to resolve this?  The MO where I have this error is now somehow "locked" and I can't delete it from the DB, no matter what I try.  My app is in production, so I can't just delete the whole app/DB and start over.

Comment: i had the same issue. I guess your code is making the update for the same row twice .